# Mathematica not able to calculate known principal value using Integrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, physics

I am trying to calculate the principal value integral -
$$I = P\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{g(x)}{y-x}dx$$ where $$g(x) = f_{1}(x) - f_2(x)$$ $$ f_i(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{\beta_{i}(x-\mu_{i})}} $$ $$y = 200*1.6*10^{-19}$$ $$ \beta_{1} = \beta_2 = \frac{1}{kT} = 2.5*10^{17} $$ $$\mu_1 = 300 * 1.6*10^{-19} $$ $$\mu_2 = 0$$

According to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.6206.pdf) (arxiv),

the integral $I$ should be, $$I = \Re[\Psi(w_2) - \Psi(w_1)]$$ where $\Psi(z)$ is the digamma function and $w_i = 0.5 + i\beta_i(y-\mu_i)/2\pi$.

But when I use Integrate to calculate the principal value, it gives me the output as an expression -

```
Integrate[(1/(1 + E^(2.5*10^17 (-4.8*10^-17 + en))) - 1/(1 + E^(2.5*10^17 (0. + en))))/(-3.2*10^-17 + en), {en, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, PrincipalValue -> True]
```

I have had no luck with using finite limits either. The output then is simply 'infinite expression $\frac{1}{0}$' and 'indeterminate expression' errors.

My code -

```
fPlus[x_, mu_, kT_] := If[(kT == 0) && (x > mu), 0, If[((kT == 0) && (x <= mu)), 1, 1/(1 + Exp[(x - mu)/kT])]];

eV = 1.6*^-19;
mu1 = 300*eV;
mu2 = 0*eV;
kT = 25*eV;
y = 200*eV;

func[en_] := (fPlus[en, mu1, kT] - fPlus[en, mu2, kT])/(en - y);

Integrate[func[en], {en, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, PrincipalValue -> True]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I don't understand why this is not working.

Answer (score 1):

First, I suppose, your "en" is also given in units of eV, therfore you have to multiply it with eV. If not, you get overflow.

Trying analytical integration with rationalized "eV" shows, there is no antiderivative for the integrand.

Therefore do numerical integration (en multiplied with eV) and you get a pretty result

```
 NIntegrate[(1/(1 + E^(2.5*10^17 (-4.8*10^-17 + en))) - 
     1/(1 + E^(2.5*10^17 (0. + en))))/(-3.2*10^-17 + en) /. 
        en -> en*eV, {en, -Infinity, Infinity}, MaxRecursion -> 200, 
     Method -> "PrincipalValue", Exclusions -> en == 200]

(*    -4.94239*10^18    *)
```